# How can I shadow the PackageManager with Robolectric

Tags: android, shadow, robolectric

My Android application has a simple method to fire off an intent to display a URL.

```
protected void launchBrowser(int id)
{
    Uri uri = Uri.parse( getString( id ) );
    Intent intent = new Intent( ACTION_VIEW, uri);

    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    if (activities.size() > 0)
    {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                       "ERROR - no application to display a web page",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I'm using Robolectric for unit testing but I'm having trouble verifying this method.  Specifically, `getPackageManager()` is always returning null.  How I can shadow the `PackageManager`?  I tried creating a `ShadowPackageManager` and calling `bindShadowClass`, but none of my code gets executed - `getPackageManager()` always returns `null`.  I also tried to Shadow the Application context and return a concrete `StubPackageManager`, but got the same results.
Maybe I've been searching/staring too long - is there a better way to unit test this method?

Comment: which context is used for calling getPackageManager? Did you try getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()

Answer (score 9):

I'm using Robolectric 2.3 for this. As noted in other answers, `getPackageManager()` does not return null, but `shadowApplication.setPackageManager` no longer exists.

Since you can't mock `PackageManager`, you can't give it a list of `Intents` to resolve for. Fortunately, Robolectric's `PackageManager` subclass, `RobolectricPackageManager`, can let you add these intents without a mock:

```
RobolectricPackageManager rpm = (RobolectricPackageManager)Robolectric.application.getPackageManager();
rpm.addResolveInfoForIntent(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS), new ResolveInfo());
```

Comment: Thanks, for **Robolectric 3.4** `RobolectricPackageManager` has been changed to `ShadowPackageManager pm = shadowOf(RuntimeEnvironment.application.getPackageManager());`

Answer (score 7):

For some reason you need to set the shadow packagemanager manually on your application.
Create a custom test runner (by extending RobolectricTestRunner) and override the setApplicationState method:

```java
public class MyTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {   
  @Override
  public void setupApplicationstate(RobolectricConfig robolectricConfig) {
     super.setupApplicationState(robolectricConfig);
     ShadowApplication shadowApplication = shadowOf(Robolectric.application);
     shadowApplication.setPackageName(robolectricConfig.getPackageName());
     shadowApplication.setPackageManager(new RobolectricPackageManager(Robolectric.application, robolectricConfig));
  }
}
```

Then specify in your tests that you want to use your own test runner:

```
@RunWith(MyTestRunner.class)
public class MyTest { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks @Jan, we tried this and it worked but would have required additional shadows/mocks to be able to generate a response for `queryIntentActivities`.  Instead we chose to override `launchBrowser()` in  a test class and assert it was called.

Answer (score 3):

I upgraded to the latest Robolectric (version 2.1.1) and the PackageManager doesn't come up `null` anymore.

The code below verifies that a browser intent is fired (and configured with a url). I haven't tested this on 1.x, but I think it works there too:

```
@Test
public void recipeTitleShouldOpenBrowserOnClick() throws Exception
{
    title.performClick();
    ShadowActivity shadowActivity = shadowOf( detailFragment.getActivity() );
    ShadowActivity.IntentForResult intent = shadowActivity.peekNextStartedActivityForResult();

    // or
    // ShadowActivity.IntentForResult intent = shadowActivity.getNextStartedActivityForResult();

    assertThat( intent.intent,
                equalTo( createBrowserIntentWithURL( "url" ) ) );
}
```

**Note**: I'm invoking start activity from a fragment here.

Answer (score 3):

Just add on to [aleph_null](https://stackoverflow.com/users/933926/aleph-null)'s answer, you can use `ShadowResolveInfo.newResolveInfo()` to quickly create a mock `ResolveInfo` ready to be used (I'm using Robolectric 2.4).

```
RobolectricPackageManager rpm = (RobolectricPackageManager)Robolectric.application.getPackageManager();
rpm.addResolveInfoForIntent(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS), ShadowResolveInfo.newResolveInfo(...));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the ShadowPackageManager in a separate method (without extending RobolectricTestRunner)

```
private void setupPackageManager() {
    ShadowApplication shadowApplication = shadowOf(Robolectric.application);
    shadowApplication.setPackageManager(mockPackageManager);
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = new ArrayList<ResolveInfo>();
    activities.add(resolveInfo("com.test.package.Class1"));
    activities.add(resolveInfo("com.test.package.Class2"));
    when(mockPackageManager.queryIntentActivities(any(Intent.class), anyInt())).thenReturn(activities);
}
```

**Note** : Here, i have used mockito & mocked the packagemanager for my unittest instead of using the actual PackageManager.

Comment: Robolectric 2.2 (at least), does not have `shadowApplication.setPackageManager()`

Answer (score 1):

For Robolectric 3.1 you can

```
RobolectricPackageManager packageManager = RuntimeEnvironment.getRobolectricPackageManager();
// add necessary logic here
```

Answer (score 0):

For version 4.9, you can use [ShadowPackageManger](https://robolectric.org/javadoc/latest/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowPackageManager.html)

And [shadowOf()](https://robolectric.org/javadoc/4.0/org/robolectric/Shadows.html#shadowOf-android.content.pm.PackageManager-)

An example is [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowPackageManager)