# Add resolve info to Robolectric package manager

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

This SO question is very similar to what I want to do: [How can I shadow the PackageManager with Robolectric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902777/how-can-i-shadow-the-packagemanager-with-robolectric)

However, all the answers rely on ShadowApplication.setPackageManager(). In 2.2, this method no longer seems to exist: http://robolectric.org/javadoc/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowApplication.html

I attempted to just grab the package manager and add a resolve info:

```
    RobolectricPackageManager packageManager = (RobolectricPackageManager) Robolectric.application.getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN,null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    ResolveInfo ri = new ResolveInfo();
    ActivityInfo ai = new ActivityInfo();
    ai.packageName = "com.fun.test";
    ri.activityInfo = ai;
    ri.isDefault = true;
    packageManager.addResolveInfoForIntent(intent, ri);
```

But to no avail. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Intent.resolveActivity is expecting the ResolveInfo to have the following:

```
if (info != null) {
    return new ComponentName(
            info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName,
            info.activityInfo.name);
}
```

So based on that, the following works for me in Robolectric 2.3:

```
RobolectricPackageManager packageManager = (RobolectricPackageManager) shadowOf(Robolectric.application).getPackageManager();
Intent intent = ... //create an Intent like the one you want to resolve

ResolveInfo info = new ResolveInfo();
info.isDefault = true;

ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = new ApplicationInfo();
applicationInfo.packageName = "com.example";
info.activityInfo = new ActivityInfo();
info.activityInfo.applicationInfo = applicationInfo;
info.activityInfo.name = "Example";

packageManager.addResolveInfoForIntent(intent, info);
```

Comment: FWIW, in later versions of Robolectric, the package manager can be retrieved using `RobolectricPackageManager packageManager = RuntimeEnvironment.getRobolectricPackageManager();`

Comment: I am getting Cannot evaluate android.content.pm.ResolveInfo.toString() as soon it hits 
    ResolveInfo info = new ResolveInfo();

I tried 
    ResolveInfo info1 = ShadowResolveInfo.newResolveInfo("Facebook", FACEBOOK_PACKAGEINFO); 
from https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/master/robolectric/src/test/java/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowPackageManagerTest.java 
Even this threw same error

Comment: In Robolectric 3.4 this is now `ShadowPackageManager packageManager = shadowOf(RuntimeEnvironment.application.getPackageManager());`.
See the migration notes for info: http://robolectric.org/migrating/

Answer (score 0):

You should adding the resolve info as a List:

```
packageManager.addResolveInfoForIntent(intent, Collections.singletonsList(ri));
```