# Make Intent.resolveActivity() to return true in a Roboletric test

Tags: android, android-testing, robolectric

I can't find a way to make robolectric resolve an activity. I need to test the following piece of code and simulate resolveActivity to return true.

```
val intent = Intent(ACTION_DIAL)
 if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
    context.startActivity(intent)
} else {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Cannot launch dialer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In real life, the result of resolveActivity is really up to what's in the app and what app is in the device. So all we can do is to configure Robolectric so that both code path (resolveActivity == null or nor) are covered in unit test.

We configure what is to be returned by Intent.resolveActivity with ShadowPackageManager. Refer to [Add resolve info to Robolectric package manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638455/add-resolve-info-to-robolectric-package-manager) for details. Note that Robolectric 3.x and 2.x has different code styles to do so.