# Robolectric + facebook sdk. Initialization error

Tags: android, facebook, robolectric

I want to get started with testing my code using robolectric. I wrote my first test for my application class, but I can't pass it because of facebook SDK initialization exception.

I also have couple of build variants (i.e "debug", "release") which use different facebook app ids, which is being set from gradle build flavors. 
Thank you in advance.

Application:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    ...
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    FacebookSdk.getApplicationId();
  }
}
```

Test:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21, application = MyApplication.class)
public class ApplicationTests {

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        assertTrue(false);
      }
    }
```

Error I keep getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.robolectric.res.builder.DefaultPackageManager.getActivityInfo(DefaultPackageManager.java:173)
at com.facebook.internal.Validate.hasFacebookActivity(Validate.java:178)
at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.java:160)
at eu.testApplication.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:116)
at org.robolectric.internal.ParallelUniverse.setUpApplicationState(ParallelUniverse.java:140)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.setUpApplicationState(RobolectricTestRunner.java:433)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:240)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:152)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Answer (score 1):

according to [#2201](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2201) issue on GitHub, you forgot to set `DefaultPackageManager`.

Read this: [How can I shadow the PackageManager with Robolectric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902777/how-can-i-shadow-the-packagemanager-with-robolectric)

or add these lines of code to yours:

```
RobolectricPackageManager rpm = (RobolectricPackageManager)Robolectric.application.getPackageManager();
rpm.addResolveInfoForIntent(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS), new ResolveInfo());
```

also I think you forgot to setup your activity like this:

```
   FacebookActivity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(FacebookActivity.class);
```

Hope it helps